# Laravel 8 relationship with two columns in each table

Tags: laravel-8

I have a multiple DB connection in Laravel 8 projects, I can't modify one of them which is mainly used in ROR project.

I need to fetch data from two tables only if `id1, id2` columns have same value in both the tables. I went on google but did not find anything.

I tried some examples, either it is giving me N+1 query issue or second table o/p always null

```
function example()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Model::class, 'id1', 'id1')->where('id2', $this->id2);
    }
```

```
function example()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Model::class, 'id1,id2', 'id1,id2');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution from https://laravel.io/forum/06-26-2014-one-to-one-relationship-with-two-fieldscolumns-connection-how

I used `join` with Laravel relation query:

```
HouseHold::where("printedcardno","=","17130103-0124")->with(array('members' => function($query)
        {
            $query->leftJoin('PatientCard', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('PatientCard.HouseHoldID', '=', 'shp_members.HouseHoldID')
                ->on('PatientCard.MemberID', '=', 'shp_members.MemberID');
                
            });
        }))->get()->take(10)->toArray();
```

I think this should be good approach as it fixed N+1 query issue and getting desired o/p.